# Using processing js and java arraylist sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, processing

I'm implementing some raytracing in processing and am working with arraylists in order to sort the intersection and create a mask. Now I'd like to upload these sketches on the web using processing js. I've already tried uploading the sketches before I implemented the arraylist and they worked.

The relevant code is a follows:

```
 import java.util.*; 
   ArrayList<Intersection> myIntersects; 

   void setup(){ 
   myIntersects = new ArrayList<Intersection>(); 

   //some code initializing the intersections and adding them to the arraylist
   }

   void draw(){
   Collections.sort(myIntersects); 
   }

   class Intersection implements Comparable<Intersection> {
   float angle; 

   //constructor and other functions

   public int compareTo(Intersection intersect){ 
   int result = 0; 
   float temp = angle - intersect.angle;
   if (temp < 0){ 
       result = -1; 
   } else if (temp > 0){
       result = 1; 
   } else {
       result = 0; 
   }
   return result; 
}
```

Is there a way to sort the intersections that is allowed by processing js?
(Or maybe an extension for processing js such that it allows sorting)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays are already flexible, so you don't really need an ArrayList class. Just use the Array.push() function.

JavaScript arrays also have a sort() function, which takes an optional parameter of a comparison function.

Your code might look something like this:

```
var myIntersects = [];
myIntersects.push(intercept1);
myIntersects.push(intercept2);
myIntersects.sort(function(a, b){
int result = 0; 
   float temp = a.angle - b.angle;
   if (temp < 0){ 
       result = -1; 
   } else if (temp > 0){
       result = 1; 
   } else {
       result = 0; 
   }
   return result; 
});
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use the javascript arrays instead.

Comment: @Bluefarmer If you were using Processing.js, you were already using JavaScript arrays. You just weren't using them to their full potential.